# Serialize C# object to JSON with custom rules

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have following object

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //other properties
    public int IdSomethingType { get; set; } //Id of selected SomethingType
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SomethingTypes { get; set; }
}
```

`SelectListItem` consists from `ID` of `SomethingType` and `Text` representation. Actually `SomethingTypes` are used in MVC application to bind to dropdownlist.
I need to serialize it to JSON but in JSON I want to have these related properties joined together: `"SomethingType" = "Text representation"`

How can be this done using Newtonsoft?

Comment: How about you post an example of your objects and json string you would like to have?

Comment: Btw, custom json conversions can be done by implementing JsonConverter. See following documentation section for more details: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm